# send pusher notification to specific user - Laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications, pusher

In my laravel app, I want to send a notification to a specific user using Pusher.

I put this code in my method :

```
$pusher = App::make('pusher');

$pusher->trigger( 'notification-channel',
                  'notification-event', 
                   array('text' => 'this is a notification'));

return view('home');
```

and put this in home.blade.php :

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var pusher = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}");
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('notification-channel');
    channel.bind('notification-event', function(data) {
      alert(data.text);
    });
```

but this makes notification to appear to any user.
This also has another problem that the user should be only on the home page to receive the notification!

So, what should I do to send a notification to a specific user and make the user receive it from any page ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the user receive it from any page, put your Pusher code in your `layout.blade.php` if you have any. Or any other file that all pages will extends.

To make it go to a specific user, you can use the user id by appending it to the channel like

```
'notification-channel:' . $user->id
```

So in your layout file you listen to that channel

```
var user = <?php echo $user ; ?>;
var channel = pusher.subscribe('notification-channel:' + user.id);
```

Although only user with that easy might receive the notification, your notification remains public. Meaning anyone can manipulate their id and receive someone else notifications. If you want private notifications, you can follow instructions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#authorizing-channels

Comment: Trying this, I got this error :
 PusherException in Pusher.php line 257:
Invalid channel name notification-channel:22  @EddyTheDove

Comment: My bad, try replacing the colon by the dot. So it becomes `'notification-channel.' . $user->id;`

Comment: The channel naming convention doesn't allow ":" character. So, I fixed this error by changing the channel name to 'notification-channel-' . $user->id    @EddyTheDove

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. That's why I suggested to use a dot instead. However, working with laravel 5.4, I use colon for my channels. like `user:update` and so on...

Comment: I'm using JWT auth in my laravel app. So, how can I get user_id from the token inside <script> tags in my blade ??  @EddyTheDove

Comment: Doesn't matter what you use, get the user however you can, either through `Auth::user()` or simply passing it to the view from controller. You don't actually need the user per se. You could just pass a variable with the user's id. Like in your controller you do `return view('viewname', ['userid' => 1]);`